# how to remove an erroneous data from data frame in R

Tags: r

I know this is a VERY general title, but bear with me, this is more about data manipulation than data cleaning.

My data set is a 1-min precipitation data.

Allow me to set up a dummy data:

```
a<-data.frame(matrix(c("00:00", "00:01","00:02", "00:03", 
"00:04","00:05","00:06","00:07","00:08","00:09","00:10",
"00:11","00:12", 1.2, 1.4 ,1.4, 1.5, 0.7, 0.8, 0.69, 1.2, 
1.0, 1.3, 0.6, 0.2, 0, 0,0, 0 , 0, 0 , 0 , 96.6, 0 , 0 , 
0 , 0, 0 ,0),ncol=3))

names(a)<-c("time","day1","day2")
a$time<-as.POSIXct(a$time, format="%Y%m%d %H:%M")
```

So now, the dataframe now looks like this

```
                  time day1 day2
1  2018-06-06 00:00:00  1.2    0
2  2018-06-06 00:01:00  1.4    0
3  2018-06-06 00:02:00  1.4    0
4  2018-06-06 00:03:00  1.5    0
5  2018-06-06 00:04:00  0.7    0
6  2018-06-06 00:05:00  0.8    0
7  2018-06-06 00:06:00 0.69 96.6
8  2018-06-06 00:07:00  1.2    0
9  2018-06-06 00:08:00    1    0
10 2018-06-06 00:09:00  1.3    0
11 2018-06-06 00:10:00  0.6    0
12 2018-06-06 00:11:00  0.2    0
13 2018-06-06 00:12:00    0    0
```

There is an odd data 96.6 there.I'd like to remove it.

I cant use outlier method because this is rainfall dataset, so the value of 96.6mm is possible if the adjacent rows show similar or close number like in day 1, but it is not possible to rain 96.6mm for just 1-min, so it is possible that this data is an error.

But how do I instruct the computer to read the adjacent rows, and if there are over 10 rows of 0, then remove any values > 50 mm?

note: the average rainfall value per min is only about 1-2mm.

Comment: Do you mean 10 rows of 0 in a row or 10 0's anywhere? because if in a row, the example you gave would not delete 96.6, since it is right in the middle

Comment: And just an idea, you could have a sliding window, get a distribution within that window, set what standard deviation away from mean would still may makes sense and set everything above that value to NA, 0 or mean depending on the context. Repeat this iteratively and it could be more robust since it does not require everything to be 0, just eliminates spikes which sounded like what you wanted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Addressing your specific question "But how do I instruct the computer to read the adjacent rows, and if there are over 10 rows of 0, then remove any values > 50 mm?" For my answer, I am only looking at the previous 5 rows. I also didn't remove the values, but you can set them to NA instead of 0 if you need.

**Data**

```
a<-data.frame( time = c("00:00", "00:01","00:02", "00:03", 
                       "00:04","00:05","00:06","00:07","00:08","00:09","00:10",
                       "00:11","00:12","00:13","00:14","00:15"),
               day1 = c(1.2, 1.4 ,1.4, 1.5, 0.7, 0.8, 0.69, 1.2, 
                       1.0, 1.3, 0.6, 0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0),
               day2 = c(0,0, 0 , 0, 0 , 0 , 96.6, 0 , 0 , 
                       0 , 0, 0 ,0, 60, 30, 600))

                  time day1 day2
1  2018-06-06 00:00:00 1.20  0.0
2  2018-06-06 00:01:00 1.40  0.0
3  2018-06-06 00:02:00 1.40  0.0
4  2018-06-06 00:03:00 1.50  0.0
5  2018-06-06 00:04:00 0.70  0.0
6  2018-06-06 00:05:00 0.80  0.0
7  2018-06-06 00:06:00 0.69 96.6
8  2018-06-06 00:07:00 1.20  0.0
9  2018-06-06 00:08:00 1.00  0.0
10 2018-06-06 00:09:00 1.30  0.0
11 2018-06-06 00:10:00 0.60  0.0
12 2018-06-06 00:11:00 0.20  0.0
13 2018-06-06 00:12:00 0.00  0.0
14 2018-06-06 00:13:00 0.00 60.0
15 2018-06-06 00:14:00 0.00 30.0
16 2018-06-06 00:15:00 0.00 600.0
```

I added a few of data points at the end to see what would happen if there were two errors in a row (or two that were close together).

**Solution**

```
library(RcppRoll)
a %>% 
  transmute(time, day1, day2 = ifelse(lag(roll_sumr(day2, 5)) == 0 & day2 > 50, 0, day2))
```

**Output**

```
                  time day1 day2
1  2018-06-06 00:00:00 1.20    0
2  2018-06-06 00:01:00 1.40    0
3  2018-06-06 00:02:00 1.40    0
4  2018-06-06 00:03:00 1.50    0
5  2018-06-06 00:04:00 0.70    0
6  2018-06-06 00:05:00 0.80    0
7  2018-06-06 00:06:00 0.69    0
8  2018-06-06 00:07:00 1.20    0
9  2018-06-06 00:08:00 1.00    0
10 2018-06-06 00:09:00 1.30    0
11 2018-06-06 00:10:00 0.60    0
12 2018-06-06 00:11:00 0.20    0
13 2018-06-06 00:12:00 0.00    0
14 2018-06-06 00:13:00 0.00   30
15 2018-06-06 00:14:00 0.00  600
```

If you want to do some sort of rolling distribution, there are some things to consider, but you could code it with something like this:

```
a %>% 
  transmute(time, day1, 
            day2 = ifelse(day2 > 3*lag(roll_sdr(day2, 5)) & !is.na(lag(roll_sdr(day2, 5))), 
                          lag(roll_meanr(day2, 5)), 
                          day2))
```

**Output**

```
                  time day1 day2
1  2018-06-06 00:00:00 1.20    0
2  2018-06-06 00:01:00 1.40    0
3  2018-06-06 00:02:00 1.40    0
4  2018-06-06 00:03:00 1.50    0
5  2018-06-06 00:04:00 0.70    0
6  2018-06-06 00:05:00 0.80    0
7  2018-06-06 00:06:00 0.69    0
8  2018-06-06 00:07:00 1.20    0
9  2018-06-06 00:08:00 1.00    0
10 2018-06-06 00:09:00 1.30    0
11 2018-06-06 00:10:00 0.60    0
12 2018-06-06 00:11:00 0.20    0
13 2018-06-06 00:12:00 0.00    0
14 2018-06-06 00:13:00 0.00    0
15 2018-06-06 00:14:00 0.00   30
16 2018-06-06 00:15:00 0.00   18
```

You see that it is finding the incorrect 96.6 and changing it to the mean of the previous 5 values (which is 0). For the 60 value in day 2, it is doing the same thing. The 30 does not get changed because it is not more than 3 standard deviations of the previous 5 values. The 600 is greater than 3 standard deviations above the previous 5 values so it changes it to the mean of the previous 5 values. You may need to tweek/iterate this procedure to get what you want.

Comment: i upvoted your answer because it's so smart--use the mean of the five top and bottom number wow! Haven't try it on my real dataset though. Will report back once I have tried it.

Comment: Hi, I repeated the example using a simple 4 columns, and tried to apply the command on day2, but it doesn't work. Could you explain why?  This is what I typed  b<-a %>% 
+     transmute(time, day1, day2, day3, day4 = ifelse(lag(roll_sumr(day2, 5)) == 0 & day2 > 50, 0, day2))

Comment: Hey I've found the solution. Tweaked around the command and found this b<-a %>% + transmute(time, day1, day2 = ifelse(lag(roll_sumr(day2, 5)) == 0 & day2 > 50, 0, day2), day3, day4)  

I will try it on my real dataset now and report back the result

Comment: Glad to hear it!

Answer (score 0):

You can use make use of `diff` in base R. Define a function with a threshold and check with `which` to see what errors should be removed. The rows will not be deleted, but the error value will receive it's previous value instead.

```
flattenSpikes <- function(x, threshold) {
  diffprev <- diff(x)
  x[which(diffprev > threshold) + 1] <- x[which(diffprev > threshold)]
  return(x)
}

a[,-1] <- mapply(flattenSpikes, a[,-1], 50)

a
#    time                day1    day2
# 1  2018-06-06 00:00:00 1.20    0
# 2  2018-06-06 00:01:00 1.40    0
# 3  2018-06-06 00:02:00 1.40    0
# 4  2018-06-06 00:03:00 1.50    0
# 5  2018-06-06 00:04:00 0.70    0
# 6  2018-06-06 00:05:00 0.80    0
# 7  2018-06-06 00:06:00 0.69    0
# 8  2018-06-06 00:07:00 1.20    0
# 9  2018-06-06 00:08:00 1.00    0
# 10 2018-06-06 00:09:00 1.30    0
# 11 2018-06-06 00:10:00 0.60    0
# 12 2018-06-06 00:11:00 0.20    0
# 13 2018-06-06 00:12:00 0.00    0
```

Data

```
a<- structure(list(time = c("00:00", "00:01", "00:02", "00:03", "00:04", 
                               "00:05", "00:06", "00:07", "00:08", "00:09", "00:10", "00:11", 
                               "00:12"), day1 = c(1.2, 1.4, 1.4, 1.5, 0.7, 0.8, 0.69, 1.2, 1, 
                                                  1.3, 0.6, 0.2, 0), day2 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 96.6, 0, 0, 0, 
                                                                              0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("time", "day1", "day2"), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                           -13L), class = "data.frame")

a$time<-as.POSIXct(a$time, format="%H:%M")
```